# How to render two attributes if variable is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman

I'm very new to ruby templating and am trying to figure ut a best-practice for rendering attributes.

I get my values from a yaml file, for example:

```
about:
    itemtype: SoftwareApplication
```

I then output them using the function t:

```
t(about.itemtype)
```

(about happens to be the page_class for the page)

What I want to do is output two attributes:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication">
```

If the item type is set. Otherwise, I don't want to output anything.

```
<div>
```

I understand I could do an inline if-statement, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Middleman, but you can use a helper method to decorate the output of your `t(about.itemtype)` with additional content in Rails.

Comment: something like this   `def itemtype(name)
     "itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/#{name}\"" if name
  end`

Comment: Yup, that would work. I'd recommend a decorator if this was an attribute from an ActiveRecord model. http://johnotander.com/rails/2014/03/07/decorators-on-rails/

Comment: The main idea is to call a method instead of a data attribute directly. This method takes care of the conditional logic.